# Existe um script/código base para email marketing?

Tags: envio-de-email

Eu quero desenvolver uma plataforma de email marketing e autoresponders, como Aweber, Mailchimp e afins (mas bem mais básico).

Pesquisei 'e-mail marketing' no google e encontrei DEZENAS de plataformas e sites que oferecem esse serviço.

Então pensei que deve existir um código base / script que as empresas pegam, modificam, personalisam e então vendem o serviço.

O problema é que não sei como pesquisar por isso, que palavras utilizar ou o nome desse tipo de código... então, onde posso encontrar?

Answer (score 0):

Tem um projeto OpenSource chamado [Mautic](https://www.mautic.org/). Com ele você consegue fazer campanhas, teste A/B, atribui pontos aos leads, etc...

Comment: Eu já cheguei a olhar o Mautic, mas surgiu uma dúvida... Posso habilitar alguma função de multi usuários em que eu terei uma página para que cada cliente crie uma conta separada dos outros clientes?

Comment: Acho que o Mautic não tem essa função, mas você pode implementar.